# How to iterate through groups without sorting?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a carefully sorted dataframe like this:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['b', 'e','e', 'g','g', 'f','f'],
                  'col2':['f', 'g','f', 'f','e', 'g','e'],
                  'col3':[ 1 ,  7 , 2 ,  6 , 7 ,  20, 5 ]})
```

I want to summarize the groups to one row each, preserving the order

```
names, totals, fs = zip(* list( (name, total(group), f(group)) for name, group in x.groupby('col1'))  )

out =   pd.DataFrame({'lang':names,
                      'total':totals,
                      'partners':tails})
```

But in `out` rows are sorted by `col1`. While `x.groupby('col1').heads()` yields everything in correct order, iterating as in `[name for name, _ in x.groupby('col1')]` returns `['b', 'e', 'f', 'g']` when 'f' should stay behind 'g'

How can I loop through groups without sorting?

Comment: Does `groupby("col1", sort=False)` give what you need? It would be good if you posted a minimal example with expected outcome.

Comment: @Cleb that's all I needed! Thank you so much! I should have checked the documentation, but I didn't expect you could disable that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, all you need is

```
groupby("col1", sort=False)
```

Taken from [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> sort : boolean, default True
>
> Sort group keys. Get better performance by turning this off. Note this does not influence the order of observations within each group.
>   groupby preserves the order of rows within each group.